# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable error using Selenium Java with Edge WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, selenium-java

Code trials:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Mftadminui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {`
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\shantha_mh\\Desktop\\SeleniumAutomation\\msedgedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("https://test.idp.idm.cms.gov/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("okta-signin-username")).sendKeys("HNAJ");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Hs229988");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='tandc']")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='tandc']")).isSelected());
        driver.findElement(By.className("button-primary")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='o-form-input-name-answer o-form-control okta-form-input-field input-fix']")));
        WebElement mfaInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='o-form-input-name-answer o-form-control okta-form-input-field input-fix']"));
        String userInput = mfaInput.getAttribute("value");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='o-form-input-name-answer o-form-control okta-form-input-field input-fix']")).click();
        mfaInput.sendKeys(" ");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input76")).click();
```

I was trying to automate the MFA User input, code reaches till the MFA input page and getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable.

Exploring one of the previous posts, but I couldn't figure out what the problem was in this code. Please assist me.

Comment: could you add more logs so that we can check where the error occurs and what's the problematic element.

Comment: _org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable_: At which line?

Comment: I stuck in the last two steps mfaInput.sendKeys(" ");
        driver.findElement(By.id("input76")).click();

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Any reason to blockquote the error message? I feel code block and error logs both should be trated as _Code Sample_ as they are easier to understand. "Block Quote" adds unnecessry line breaks.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Because that makes the entire error message readable without scrolling, if it had been an exception stacktrace, then a code block is more appropriate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ofcorase it's a part of the an exception stacktrace.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium The OP did not post the exception stacktrace, they only posted the message.

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear at which step you are stuck. However to send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` fields you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://test.idp.idm.cms.gov/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#okta-signin-username"))).sendKeys("HNAJ");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#okta-signin-password")).sendKeys("Hs229988");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='Agree to terms and conditions']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#okta-signin-submit")).click();
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: GoogleAuthenticator]

Comment: Expecting the code to wait until the user Enter Google Authenticator Code and click on Verify as I have last line of code. The code starting from WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)); is written for this purpose.

Comment: You expect StackOverflow volunteer contributors to install Google Authenticator to solve this question?

Comment: While reviewing the log (I don't know how to attach it here on stack overflow), I see that the Exception in thread "main" element not interactable error using Selenium Java with Edge WebDriver points to the last line of code in my shared code. There is something missing for the wait to not working to process after I input the MFA code.

Comment: @user18815229 Ideally I should have closed this question as you haven't supplied the text based relevant HTML. Please update the question accordingly.